# D3 Labels text amount slightly off

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a problem with my D3 bar chart not displaying the correct amount for the label text. It seems like it's slightly off, and I'm not sure why.

I'm trying to get the text labels to display whatever the newNumber is within the dataset.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
     var w = 800;
  var h = 600;
  var padding = 5;
  var maxNumber = 100;

  //Generate random numbers
  var dataset = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
             var newNumber = Math.random() * maxNumber;
             dataset.push(newNumber);
            }

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
   .rangeRoundBands([padding, w - padding], 0.05);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([d3.max(dataset), 0])
   .range([padding, h - padding]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(xScale)
   .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(yScale)
   .orient("left");

  var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i) + padding;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d) - padding - 15;
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("fill", "rgba(95, 159, 229, 0.3");

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .transition().delay(function(d, i) {
        return i / dataset.length * 800;
    })
    .duration(1500)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d) - padding - 15;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
     return yScale(d);
    });

   svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return Math.floor(d3.max(dataset) - d);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i) + padding + 15;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d) - padding - 20;
      })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "11px")

  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "xAxis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding - 15) + ")")
   .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "yAxis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding + 15) + ",0)")
   .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3: BDAS Bar Chart Test</title>

  <style>
   svg {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 30px;
   }

   rect {
    transition: 0.1s;
   }
   rect:hover {
    fill: rgba(95, 159, 229, 1);
   }

   .xAxis path, .yAxis path {
    fill: #aaa;
    height: 0.5px;
   }

   .xAxis .tick text, .yAxis .tick text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    fill: #aaa;
    font-size: 15px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: by "text labels" do you mean the values shown on the top of each bar? I noticed that couple of things going wrong in your visualization so I dont get which one do you want to fix?

Comment: Yeah, the labels on top of the bars aren't computing properly.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your coded and changed it a bit and it should work now.

```
   var w = 800 ;
    var h = 600 ;
    var padding = 20;

    //Generate random numbers
    var dataset = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
            var newNumber = Math.random() *100;
            dataset.push(newNumber);
        }

    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
        .rangeRoundBands([padding, w - padding], 0.05);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,d3.max(dataset)])
        .range([h - padding,padding]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale(i);})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d);})
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("fill", "rgba(95, 159, 229, 0.3")
            .attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d) - padding; });

    svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .transition().delay(function(d, i) { return i / dataset.length * 800;})
            .duration(1500)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d);})
            .attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d) - padding; });

        svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                return Math.floor(d);
           })
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return (xScale(i)+15);
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                console.log(h-yScale(d))
                return (yScale(d)-padding) ;
           })
           .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
           .attr("font-size", "11px")

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h-padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "yAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding + 10) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, although I'm still not sure why the other code was computing improperly.

Comment: You did not do the yScale correctly. So this influenced your bars positioning.